# Why won't this rspec test pass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I've spent the last hour trying to figure out why this test won't pass.

I'm working in Rails 4.0 with Capybara 2.1.0 and rspec 2.14.1

Here's my test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Stats" do
subject { page }
describe "Index Page" do
    before { visit stats_path }
    it { should have_selector 'h1', text: 'Stats' }
end
end
```

And my index.html.erb file:

```
<h1>Stats</h1>
<table>
  <thead>
<tr>
  <th>Attendance</th>
  <th>Salvations</th>
  <th>Visitors</th>
  <th>Offering</th>
  <th>Service Date</th>
  <th>Time</th>
  <th>Campus</th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
</tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @stats.each do |stat| %>
      <tr>
     <td><%= stat.attendance %></td>
    <td><%= stat.salvations %></td>
    <td><%= stat.visitors %></td>
    <td><%= stat.offering %></td>
    <td><%= stat.date %></td>
    <td><%= stat.time %></td>
    <td><%= stat.campus.name %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', stat %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_stat_path(stat) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', stat, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
 </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Stat', new_stat_path %>
```

And the error I'm getting is:

1) Stats Index Page should have css "h1" with text "Stats"
     Failure/Error: it { should have_selector 'h1', text: 'Stats' }
     Capybara::ExpectationNotMet:
       expected to find css "h1" with text "Stats" but there were no matches
     # ./spec/features/stats_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in '

I'm stumped. Any help would be appreciated.

Incidentally, my index page renders correctly without any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it works when you visit then page but not when you run your test script then there is certainly a session or authentication matter. Is your index page protected by any authentication or authorization logic?

I cannot give you a solution, but I can try to give you a guide line, if you haven't do it yet, use `pp` to output to the console the rendering of the page.

For example, if you are testing in `controllers` directory, use `pp response.body`. Or if you are testing in `views` directory, use `render` followed by `pp rendered`.

Then from the output in your console you will certainly get a clue according to your specific logic on what's append.

Comment: I hate when I miss the obvious but I'm sure grateful for stackoverflow.
That's exactly the issue. I'm using devise and forgot to authenticate in the test. Thanks

Comment: Always useful to get our head outside of our code for few minutes sometimes. Cheers :)